# How many cents would would i need to shift the pitch of the sample to change its key?

Tags: theory, key, transposition

I have a sample in C# Major that I want transposed to F# Major. How many cents would would i need to shift the pitch of the sample in order to transpose it?

Comment: *Cent* is typically used to denote, how far a tone is out of tune. For a transpoition intervals are the appropriate measure, so one would simply call it a *sixth*, because *500 cent* would imply a precision, which is not intended.

Comment: @guidot but the desired degree of precision here is probably enough that "sixth" is inaccurate.  Depending on direction, the interval between C sharp and F sharp is a fourth or a fifth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each semi-tone (half step) is 100 cents. There are five half steps between  the two pitches you mentioned... So 500 cents up. Or you could shift the pitch 700 cents down, to get it in F# an octave lower.